# WPF Windows Controller

Tags: c#, wpf

I am having some problems with WPFs.

I have a project that has multiple windows, so to control this windows, I have created a controller class. This controller will have a instance of each windows:

```
this.mainWindow = new MainWindow();
this.loginWindow = new LoginWindow();
this.registerWindow = new RegisterWindow();
```

The problem comes when I callback from any of the windows to the controller class and from this controller I want to update the information of the window (for example update the value of a property), the information is not being updated

```
// In controller
public void login(String email, String pass)
{
    ....
    this.loginWindow.showErrorInPassword();
} 

// In LoginWindow

public void showErrorInPassword()
{
    this.emailErrorImage.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
}
```

... but if I send from the LoginWindow a reference of itself to the login function on the controller, the emailErrorImage will be shown

```
public void login(String email, String pass, LoginWindow lw)
{
    ....
    lw.showErrorInPassword();
}
```

Seems that the instance that I have in the controller is not the same as the one that is being displayed when I do this.loginWindow.show()

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484(v=pandp.40).aspx) is the way to update all of the windows without passing instances of each window.  This is especially useful with redundant data.  You could use [custom events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx) from each window to call back to the controller.

Comment: @FelixCastor thanks ;) didn't know about it

Comment: add an assertion `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(lw.Equals(this.loginWindow))`, in the last method, before `lw.showErrorInPassword();`

Answer (score 2):

You are going to need to bind the UI objects to a MVVM class to update each window.

Use events to call back to the controller.

Here is a brief example.  First create a class to contain event args.  Doesn't really have to contain anything.  It just differentiates between different delegates.  Make it its own class in the namespace so everything has access to it.

```cs
public class SomeEventArgs: EventArgs
{
}
```

Inside the window class:

```cs
public event EventHandler<SomeEventArgs> CallBackToController;

protected virtual void OnCallBackEvent(object sender, SomeEventArgse)
{
    EventHandler<SomeEventArgs> handle = CallBackToController;

    if (handle != null)
    {
        handle(this, e);
    }
}
```

In the controller class, after instantiating the window assign the event to a method.

```cs
this.loginWindow = new LoginWindow();
this.loginWindow.CallBackToController += new EventHandler<SomeEventArgs>(MethodToHandleEvent);
```

Then the Method must have the same form as expected:

```cs
private void MethodToHandleEvent(object sender, SomeEventArgs e)
{
    // Do something in response.
}
```

Now anytime you call `OnCallBackEvent(this, new SomeEventArgs())` from the window class, the controller class will catch the event and execute `MethodToHandleEvent`

For instance:

```cs
private void LoginWindowBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Logged in ok, let the controller know.
    OnCallBackEvent(this, new SomeEventArgs ());
}
```

There are a ton of tutorials on this, I think this is a better approach to passing references of windows from window to window.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it doesn't work to me. Seems that in the window instance of the controller I have the proper CallBackToController reference. But in the main window class I still have CallBackToController set as null

Comment: Use main as your controller.